# Mysql create trigger if not exist

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a script that creates triggers,
I would like to run it multiple times and if a trigger already exist it needs to skip the creation part.

Is there a "create if not exist" in mysql triggers?

I tried :

```
    IF NOT EXISTS ((SELECT TRIGGER_NAME
        FROM information_schema.triggers
        WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'xxx_admin' AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'test_AFTER_UPDATE')) 
        THEN
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `xxx_admin`.`test_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `test` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO auditTest 
        select *, now() from test where id = NEW.id;
        END;
  END IF;
```

I get : syntex error " 'IF' is not valid input at this location

Answer (score 4):

There is no [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-trigger.html) IF NOT EXISTS

There is [DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

You must execute the trigger's creation as follows:

```
USE xxx_admin
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test_AFTER_UPDATE $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `xxx_admin`.`test_AFTER_UPDATE`
AFTER UPDATE ON `test` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO auditTest 
    select *, now() from test where id = NEW.id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

As for you error, using IF like that is not valid from the CLI.

Comment: since we run it in every new version it will mean some information is lost until the trigger is created?

Comment: You need to schedule downtime of 1 min to do this. That will ensure no data loss.

Comment: I'm looking for a way that does not drop the trigger to re-create it.. I don't want any downtime if there is not reason.. the trigger does not change

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8.0 there is `CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS` syntax:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_from_code` BEFORE DELETE ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

delete from  code
where  nom = old.nom  ;

END
```

YOU CAN CREATE TRIGGERS IF NOT EXISTS LIKE THIS : –

```
String query11 ="CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS delete_prix_pack BEFORE DELETE ON users\n" + 
" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN\n" + 
"delete from prixpacketgros\n" + 
"where nom = old.nom ;\n" + 
"END" ; 
executeSQLQuery(query11);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add more details.  I have done that for you, it's waiting for review and should appear shortly.